# Behavior of built-in functions "all" and "any"

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, boolean-expression

Just something weird I noticed about the behavior of the `all` function, hoping to get a proper explanation of the logic or inner-workings.

Assume I have an empty list - `items = []` Normally it would be "falsey", i.e `bool(items)` or `bool([])` would be `False`. However, `all` treats it as `True`:

```
all([item for item in items]) # True
all(item for item in items) # True
all(items) # True
all([]) # True
```

But strangely, having an empty list inside the list, evaluates to false:

```
all([[]]) # False
```

This doesn't seem to affect the behavior of `any`:

```
any([item for item in items]) # False
any(item for item in items) # False
any(items) # False
any([]) # False
any([[]]) # False
```

I've tested it in python 3.7.5, I don't know if this is the behavior in other versions. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Not really sure what the relevance of `bool([])` would be to `any([])` and `all([])` since those functions evaluate the `bool` of the items *in* the iterable, not of the iterable itself. So of course, since `bool([])` is `False`, `all([[]])` will be `False`, since the only value in the container is falsey. For the degenerate cases (empty iterable) look at the duplicate for explanations of this behavior.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for locating this duplicate, I tried searching before I asked but didn't find this result

Comment: No problem, sometimes it isn't obvious how to construct a search query to try to find the duplicate.